# JQGRID + URL + GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

The grid is not showing any values through I am able to see the JSON values printed in the code behind file. Please find the JS code and CodeBehind listed below -

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert("Page Load1");
        createUserGrid();
        alert("Page Load2");

    });

    function createUserGrid() {
        alert("call webservice");
        $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/POWeb.asmx/GetPOCores?strPoNo=411101',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            loadonce: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            height:"auto",
            colNames: ['Number', 'Name', 'Notes'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true }, sorttype: "string" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100, sorttype: "string", editable: true },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: true }
            ],
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }
            },
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },

            rowNum: 1,
            rowList: [1, 2, 3],
            pager: '#divPager',
            editurl: 'SaveEdit.aspx',
            caption: "Users Data",
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Below is my CodeBehind file

```
namespace MenuCheck
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for POWeb
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class POWeb : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

    public List<POItems> GetPOCores(string strPoNo)
    {
        //string strPoNo = "411101";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" In Web Method");

        List<POItems> result = null;
        DB dbobj = new DB();
        result = dbobj.getPOItems(strPoNo, 0);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASMX model allows to returns objects serialized as XML or JSON. The .NET framework do the serialization for you. So it's error to call `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize` manually. The method `GetPOCores` should returns object which represents required data instead of string.

So what you should do is to declare the class like

```
public class MyItem {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
}
```

(the exact types of names can depends on your data). You can change signature of the web method `GetPOCores` to

```
public List<MyItem> GetPOCores(string strPoNo)
```

and adjust its code to return `List<MyItem>` without any manual serialization.

You should add `loadonce: true` option because you don't implemented paging of data on the server side. I recommend you to add additionally `gridview: true, autoencode: true` options and consider to remove `width` option and use `height: "auto"`. In the case the grid width will be the sum of `width` values of all columns of `colModel`. Additionally you will need to include the following `jsonReader` option in jqGrid:

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }
}
```

add

```
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
```

and

```
serializeGridData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your reply. I have updated my code. Web method is not called and jgrid is not loaded . Please let me know my mistake in code.